# how to access arraylist, string array, or list from javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to call one javascript function from my button click on server side and pass the arraylist, string array or list as a parameter to the function.
I would then need to iterate through all the elements of these collection and perform some action on the data.
Can you tell me the javascript code to access these element
Consider the following structure that I have in the Javascript

```
Function ABC(_Arraylist/List/String Array){

//I would like to perform some action on the collections data here.
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: See [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Answer (score 3):

Server:

```
// this could also be a string[] if you prefer
var array = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var script = string.Format("foo({0});", serializer.Serialize(array));
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "call", script, true);
```

Client:

```
function foo(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        alert(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the reference class new to add to call "JavaScriptSerializer" function ?

Comment: @PankajGarg, here it is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx . Namespace: `System.Web.Script.Serialization`, Assembly: `System.Web.Extensions.dll`.

Comment: +1 for JavaScript Serializer. If you try to pass the argument without serialize it will give the illegal character runtime error at Javascript console